# Javascript - return array length in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to get an array's length and display it on a page, like so:

```
var someArray = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'];

var getArrayLength = function() {
    return someArray.length;
}

getArrayLength();
```

For some reason this isn't working. I tried to replace the element's innerHTML, same issue.

```
<p id="demo"></p>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = someArray.length;
```

Even if I set a variable equal to `someArray.length` and then return the variable it doesn't work. I don't get any errors, just no result. Is there something special about returning the length of an array in a function?

I was able to pull this off using jQuery, I'm just curious as to what I was doing wrong with the vanilla javascript.

Comment: What "doesn't work" exactly mean? "just no result" --- every expression in JS returns some result. Your provided code works just fine, try it yourself.

Comment: Probably not waiting for the page to load. Is your script before or after the `p` element?

Comment: Try logging with console.log(). If you get number, try using .innerText instead.

Comment: You call your function and then immediately discard its result. So what do you expect to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the `innerHTML` (or `textContent` which is better) after the document is loaded. Try this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").textContent = someArray.length;
});
```

jQuery code was working because it's internally waiting for the load event (assuming that you've wrapped your code inside `$(function() {...})`).

Comment: Thanks, the issue was with the document not being fully loaded.

Answer (score 3):

You don't even have to declare any functions.

```js
var someArray = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'];

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = someArray.length;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks, it turned out to be related to the order the page was loading.

Answer (score 1):

actually your code is working but you are not actually trying to display anything. in your case add something actually giving you output.

```
var someArray = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'];

var getArrayLength = function() {
    return someArray.length;
}

console.log(getArrayLength());
alert(getArrayLength());
```